# how can i read array like in picture (python)

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBM8H.png)

I want to read a 2-dimensional array column by column in python and then print the message in reverse. How can I do this?

like this image

here is my code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

def get_the_message(image, sentinel): 
    image = Image.open(image)
    width, height = image.size
    bitplane = numpy.zeros((height, width))
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            pixel = image.getpixel((x, y))
            lsb = pixel & 1
            bitplane[y, x] = lsb

    message = ""
    bitbuffer = ""
    for j in range(width):
        for i in range(height):
            bitbuffer = bitbuffer + str(int(bitplane[i,j]))
            if len(bitbuffer) == 8:
                character = chr(int(bitbuffer, 2)``your text``)
                if character == sentinel:
                    break
                else:
                    message = message + str(character)
                    bitbuffer = ""
        if character == sentinel:
            break

    return message

print(get_the_message('abc.image', '+'))
```

my code writes

```
g s  m #
```

I want to print this order in my code:

```
m s g #
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. I think it's more helpful if you step through your program using a debugger, or if that is not your thing, add more print statements inside the for loops.